# How to get the result of a list item in turn

Tags: rx-java

There is a list of elements, each element is able to play your animation. animation method returns `Observable` and ended when the animation is called `subscriber.onNext(); subscriber.onCompleted();`.

Then I'm doing

```
Observable.from (items)
                 .flatMap (item :: startAnimation)
                 .subscribe ();
```

How to make what would be the next item animation started after the end of the previous animation? So they start at the same time

```
public Observable<Boolean> startAnimation(){
        return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        Action action = new Action() {
            @Override
            public boolean act(float delta) {
                subscriber.onNext(true);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
                return true;
            }
        };

        if(moveToAction != null){
            SequenceAction sequenceAction = new SequenceAction(moveToAction, action);
            main.addAction(sequenceAction);
        }else{
            subscriber.onNext(true);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
    }
```

Aсtion object is a listener end animation

Comment: Can you please paste startAnimation method which returns observable??

Comment: i am add `startAnimation` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `flatMap` use `concatMap` ; it will subscribe to item `n+1` when item `n` has completed.

Comment: Thank you, this is what you need